# How to create image slider that stops on mouse hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code

```
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">             
       <div>
           <img src="assets/images/home-banner.jpg" width="995" height="421" alt=""/>
       </div>
       <div>
           <img src="assets/images/banner1.jpg" width="995" height="421" alt=""/> 
       </div>
       <div>
           <img src="assets/images/home-banner.jpg" width="995" height="421" alt=""/> 
       </div>
       <div>
           <img src="assets/images/banner1.jpg" width="995" height="421" alt=""/> 
       </div>
       </div>
<script>
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
       setInterval(function() { 
         $('#slideshow > div:first')
          .fadeOut(1000)
          .next()
          .fadeIn(1000)
          .end()
          .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try following jQuery and tell if it is working or not ??

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timer;

    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    $("#slideshow")
        .mouseenter(function() {
            if (timer) { clearInterval(timer) }
        })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                $("#slideshow > div:first")
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo("#slideshow");
            }, 2000);
        })
        .mouseleave();


});
```

Methods setInterval() returns a intervalID that you can use to clear the current interval/timeout using clearInterval().
And Here is a working [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cvxe2/138/)

Answer (score 0):

first it is kind of hard to do it with your code it should be reformattd as a function havig as role to do sliding images let's supposte that function having as name animate_slider() , well to stop it on mouseover you just need to set a clearInterval on time parameter like this :

```
var time=setInterval("animate_slider()",3000);
    $('div#slideshow').mouseover(function(){
        clearInterval(time);
    });
```